# Pop up box for alarm not appearing?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios-simulator

In my app i am using alarm functionality. Its working fine but when i am testing in **simulator** the alarm notified with the popup box. In **real device** it just come as notification in status bar instead of popup box.

I am looking for popup box in real device. I am not sure what i am doing wrong here?

I am using this code for my alarm

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

localNotification.fireDate = date;

localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification.alertBody = alarmMessage;
localNotification.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"View", nil);
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;

/* Here we set notification sound and badge on the app's icon "-1"
 means that number indicator on the badge will be decreased by one
 - so there will be no badge on the icon */


NSString *ringtonename = [lblRingToneName text];
NSString *extension = @".caf";

NSString  *ringtone = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@%@", ringtonename, extension];

localNotification.soundName = ringtone;
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = -1;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Thanks for your help guys

Comment: hi is your code localNotification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit; working fine....?

Comment: Yeah thats working fine Rajneesh

Comment: i am also working on such type app....but when i log the fire date its  show different date but local noti comes on perfect time...why this show diff date in log?

Comment: Dont worry.. That is because your country time differ from GMT time thats the only reason..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the device is locked the notification would displayed as pop box,if a app is running the notification would displayed in status bar, there is nothing about your code.

Comment: Thanks Veelian.. Thats really simple..+1

Comment: @Vino first install? You mean first time open the app? you can save a variable in a file, then change the value after opened it.

Answer (score 1):

When a UILocalNotification is fired, there are 3 possibilities:

- Your app is running in the background or is closed: your local notification will appear according to the settings the user defined: it may appear as a banner, as a UIAlertView, or not to appear at all.
- Your app is running in the foreground: You can receive, in your AppDelegate class, any local notification with the following method:

  `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification`
- The device is locked: the device will show an alert in the locked screen (or won't if the user defined so)

Comment: Thanks for your answer..Is that possible to enable UIAlertView when the user first installs the app..

Comment: No, you can't play with the user's notification settings.

Comment: Oh Ok thanks.. Just one simple question.. If the user is in phone call.. If the alarm get notified can i reduce the alarm sound to 10 seconds.. Is that possible?

Comment: I'm not sure about it. I **think** you can't. Please vote up if the answer was good and/or helped.